# Rails 3.1 validates uniqueness of nested attributes for polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, nested-attributes

Given the following models:

```
##Invoice.rb
has_many :line_items, :as => :line_itemable
accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items

##LineItem.rb
belongs_to :line_itemable, :polymorphic => true
validates :employee_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :scope => [ :line_itemable_id, :line_itemable_type ] }
```

How would I go about validating the following new invoice

```
i = Invoice.new
i.line_items << [ LineItem.new( :employee_id => 1 ), LineItem.new( :employee_id => 1 ) ]
i.valid?
```

The invoice should not be valid because the line_items employee_id's are the same and yet no error is thrown and the line_items are added to the database. If the Invoice is an existing record the validations do work.

Any ideas? Is this a bug?

To prevent bad data I have added the following index but would like to have the proper rails validations

```
add_index :line_items, [ :employee_id, :line_itemable_type, :line_itemable_id ], :unique => true, :name => 'index_line_item_employee_id'
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I just ran into the same problem.  It seems like because the line_itemable_id's aren't filled in yet and are nil, the validation doesn't fail.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to code exactly as you did, but the only way that I find to bypass this was to write a custom validate in the Invoice class. This solution has a drawback that the problematic fields doesn't get highlighted.